# Как разделить txt файл по главам?

Tags: java

Есть документ в формате txt, не форматированный.
В документе присутствует некое количество абзацев (порядка 130) озаглавленных
`Глава 1`, `Глава 2`, `Глава 3` и т.д.

Существует ли способ разбить такой документ на множество мелких файлов так, чтобы каждый файл содержал одну главу?
Собственно, был интересен пример реализации в коде. Предпочтение языку не делалось.

Вот какое решение реализовал для себя на Jave

```
public class ReadLoadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File fileForRead = new File("/home/user/Text.txt");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    File fileForLoad = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileForRead),"cp1251"));
        String s;
        boolean firstPart = true;
        while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            if(s.contains("Глава")){
                if (firstPart){
                    fileForLoad = new File("/home/user/PartOfText/Введение.txt");
                    fileForLoad.createNewFile();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileForLoad),"UTF-8"));
                    bufferedWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append(s);
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    fileForLoad = new File("/home/user/PartOfText/"+s);
                    fileForLoad.createNewFile();
                    firstPart = false;
                }else{
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileForLoad),"UTF-8"));
                    bufferedWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append(s);
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    fileForLoad = new File("/home/user/PartOfText/"+s);
                    fileForLoad.createNewFile();
                }
            }else{
                stringBuilder.append(s);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
        }
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileForLoad),"UTF-8"));
        bufferedWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        bufferedWriter.flush();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: укажите язык программирования, на котором вы хотели бы получить решение (точнее, тот, на котором вы пытались решить проблему самостоятельно :)

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм примерно следующий:

1. Ищете в исходном файле фрагмент между заголовками (у последней главы заголовок будет только один);
2. Вырезаете или копируете его в новый текстовый файл.

Искать фрагменты можно разными способами: либо последовательный обход текста с поиском по ключам ("Глава1,Глава2,Глава3 и т.д"), либо использовать регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2):

Построчно читаем файл и пишем в текущий выходной файл. При обнаружении строки обозначающей начало новой главы создаем файл для этой главы и последующий вывод строк идет в него.

Короче всего это формулируется на языке `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$fname=$ARGV[0]; $fname=~s/\.txt$//;  # от имени файла переданного в командной строке отрезаем .txt
while(<>)                             # читаем входной файл
{
 if(/^\s*Глава *(\d+)\s*$/)           # Если новая глава берем ее номер в $1
  {open(STDOUT,">$fname$1.txt");}     # Открываем файл для новой главы 'имя-файлаN.txt'
 print;                               # Печатаем строку в файл
}
```

Comment: Тоесть стандартные текстовые процессоры вроде MSOffice или OpenOffice такой возможности мне не предоставять?Слабо разбираюсь в текстовых редакторах

Comment: Но вы в вопросе написали, что у вас файл .txt, а офисы работают отнюдь не с txt и учитывая, что основной тематикой StackOverflow является программирование - то ваш вопрос все воспринимают именно в таком ключе. В принципе в офисе какой нибудь язык наверняка включен, в екселе же есть VB встроенный, который это вполне мог бы сделать. Но что бы это сделать парой кликов где то в меню - я сомневаюсь

Comment: В ключе программирования  и интересовало,просто тока сейчас дошло что можно попробовать через текстовые редакторы это провернуть,Извените что ввел в заблуждение

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще короче , пусть есть файл формата :

> Glava1
> qwerqwerqwerqwerqer qwerqwerqwerqwerqer qwerqwerqwerqwerqer
>
> Glava2
> qwerqwerqwerqwerqer qwerqwerqwerqwerqer qwerqwerqwerqwerqer
> ........

shell :

```
csplit book --prefix=Glava '/^Glava/' '{*}'
```

Файл будет разбит на части по регурярке : взять все от начала строки в которой есть вхождение `Glava` и сохранен последовательно в файлы с префиксом `Glava`
`Glava00 , Glava01 ... Glava11 etc`

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант на php

```
<?php

$txtfile = 'text.txt';

$txt = file_get_contents($txtfile);
$txt = preg_split('#(?=Глава)#s', $txt);
$txt = array_map("trim", $txt);

foreach ($txt as $key => $value) {

    if ( $value ) {
        $fp = fopen($key.'_glava.txt', 'w');
        $test = fwrite($fp, $value);
        fclose($fp);
    }

}

?>
```

Исходный файл text.txt

```
Глава 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut vim feugait conclusionemque, id malis euripidis vim, eam movet signiferumque cu. Ut inani blandit sed, albucius scripserit scriptorem te pri. 
Sea id purto veniam facilisis, cu duo dicam mucius alterum, mea ut ceteros luptatum. Nam no oratio legendos, malorum ceteros ex usu. Eam in eligendi mnesarchum.

Глава 2.
Ex nec novum vocibus delectus. Fastidii officiis dissentiunt eum ad, nemore accusamus intellegat ad eam, at assum voluptua accommodare vix. Ea labore corrumpit interpretaris mei. His at saepe appellantur. 

Vis cu wisi iisque placerat, in solet dicam adversarium usu. Eum option delenit ut, et pro iracundia deseruisse, an quot vivendum scriptorem pri. Aeque ludus reprehendunt vis cu, qui justo laoreet te, aeque impetus usu ei.

Глава 3.

Eum in delenit hendrerit delicatissimi, an justo rationibus pri. Clita delicata mel ut, congue eruditi vituperatoribus cu vim. Malis soluta ei vix, deleniti reformidans neglegentur qui ne, agam expetenda eos cu. Ei ferri euismod ponderum qui, vero saperet graecis no pro, vim brute graecis ut.
```

На выходе получаем 3 файла (1_glava.txt, 2_glava.txt, 3_glava.txt)